# Lightning Card Slot Footer

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to add a checkbox next to the save button. The save and the cancel buttons are inside a lightning card P slot ="footer"
The checkbox does not appear in the same row as that of the save and cancel buttons. It's appearing in the next row.

My code:

```
<p slot= "footer">
                    <lightning-button
                            class="slds-float_none"
                            variant="neutral"
                            label="Cancel"
                            title="Cancel"
                            onclick={handleCancel}>
                    </lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button
                            class="slds-float_none"
                            variant="brand"
                            label="Save"
                            title="Save"
                            onclick={handleSave}>
                    </lightning-button>
                    <lightning-input type='checkbox'  label="Red"> 
                 </lightning-input>
</p>
```

Should I be using normal footer and lightning-layout/Layout-item instead?

Comment: Hi, Eliana. You did not add your code. Please add it so someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of the `slot` approach is that you can add *any* HTML and CSS that you want e.g. one of the [grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#Content-centered) layouts:

```
<p slot= "footer">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-button ...>
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-button ...>
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-input ...> 
            </lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

Note that the design [blueprint for cards](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/) does not place buttons where you are placing them so do check that you have a good reason for putting the buttons in the footer.

Comment: Thanks. But the Div tag inside a <p slot = "footer"> throws error that the <p> tag does not have a matching closed tag though it has </p>. So , I didn't put any checkbox and tried to display a  message instead,

Comment: Hi @Eliana, That sounds like a mismatching `<` and `</` pair.